# How to use a variable twice in C?

Tags: c

I am quite new to C and i am trying to use a variable twice in one line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int myAge = 10;
    char PL = "C";
    printf("I am Rydex (not my real name) and i am %d years old. This was made using %s", myAge, PL);
}
```

But, when i run it, I get:

> I am Rydex (not my real name) and i am 10 years old. This was made using (null)

Instead of the value in the variable "PL" i get "(null)". Can someone please help me?

Comment: Use a string instead of char

Comment: char PL might have to be const char * PL

Comment: Do you not get a compiler warning on `char PL = "C"`?  Turn up the diagnostics!

Comment: You're not using a variable twice here... The mention of a variable being used twice does not make sense in your question.

Comment: Get in the habit now of paying attention to all the warnings that your compiler gives you.  Whatever tool chain you are using to build your code, learn how to make it give you those warnings.  The code you show should not compile cleanly; if you aren't seeing warnings, you need to investigate your tool chain to discover why.

Comment: Warnings/error are mandatory since the code isn't valid C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PL is a string, not a char.  You need to change the declaration to:

```
char* PL = "C";
```

The double-quoted delimiter is for a string constant, which has a span of characters terminated with a null character \0.  A single quote delimiter is to define a single character constant.  Here's a good [write-up](https://pediaa.com/what-is-the-difference-between-character-and-string/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I can't correct this comment yet because of the cooldown lol

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
char * PL = "C";
```

To declare PL as a pointer. You probably also want `\n` at the end of your format string.

I'm surprised your compiler didn't complain that you weren't declaring a pointer. Mine did. It didn't like the string "C" (which is 2 bytes) being declared as a single character (which is equivalent to a single byte integer)

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:15: warning: initialization of ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversio ]
     char PL = "C";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you try to use `%s` in `printf` function, it expects type `char*` – a pointer to `char`. Try using `%c` instead with type `char`.

Comment: Using type `char` would also require changing `"C"` to `'C'`.

Comment: Indeed it would, and for the benefit of the OP, that would set PL to a single character (1 byte), instead of a null terminated string, and the `%c` is the correct format code for printing a single byte, vs. `%s` which expects a pointer to a null-terminated string

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Change the declaration of `PL` to

   ```
   char *PL = "C";
   ```

   or

   ```
   char PL[] = "C";
   ```

   The `%s` format specifier expects its corresponding to have type `char *` - in other words, it expects `PL` to be the address of the first character of a string.  The string `"C"` is actually an *array* of `char` containing the sequence `{'C', 0}`.  Under most circumstances, an expression of array type is converted, or "decays", to a pointer type and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

   Change the declaration of `PL` to

   ```
   int PL = 'C'; // single quotes, not double
   ```

   and use `%c` instead of `%s` in the `printf` call:

   ```
   printf("I am Rydex (not my real name) and i am %d years old. This was made using %c", myAge, PL);
   ```

   `'C'` is a *character constant*, not a string.  The `%c` format specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`.  In this case, `PL` stores the character code for `'C'` (67 in ASCII and UTF-8).

Comment: `int PL = 'C';` why not `char PL = 'C';` ?

Comment: @4386427: Character constants in C have type `int`, and the `%c` format specifier actually expects an `int`.

Comment: printf handles that for you... you don't need `int` to store a single character

Answer (score 0):

Use `char *PL = "C"` instead of `char PL = "C"`. Notice the asterisk. That is called a pointer, but that's a topic for another time.